# Changes not reflected in User Controls when debugging

Tags: asp.net, debugging, user-controls, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and have a Web Application that I am trying to squash a few bugs. Previously I was able to start debugging, make a change to the user control then refresh the page and see the change. Now I have to stop the debugger and rebuild the entire project before the change shows. I am only changing the markup (things like in-line css, HTML, etc) and not any of the code behind so a recompile shouldnt be necessary. I have verified that this is not a browser cache issue, as I have used several browsers, and cleared the cache after loading the page. I also used incognito mode to make certain nothing was cached. Any ideas on how I can fix this?